# How to make text centre aligned in a table?

Tags: tables, arrays, cv

I am new to LaTex and I am making my CV.

I want to add a table for my education section but it does not look good.

[image: Table Image]
this is not at all appealing to the eye.

Here's the code, please suggest some changes. Thank you.

```
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular} { | m {3.3 cm} | m {8.2 cm} | m {3.3 cm} | m {2.2 cm} | }
\hline
\textbf{Serial No.} & \textbf{Institute} & \textbf{Year} & \textbf{CPI/\%} \\
\hline
1 & ABC Univ & 2011-2015 & 10.0\\
2 & BCD High School  & 2011 & 91.85/100\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Be sure to load the `array` package and to change `m{...}` to `>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{...}` where needed. (E.g., I don't think it's needed for the first two columns of the `tabular` environment you posted.) Read the [user guide](https://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) of the `array` package to learn what `\arraybackslash` does.

Comment: Thank you @Mico for welcoming me, This did help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome. One more comment about your code: You may want to change `2011-2015` to `2011--2015` in order to get a so-called en-dash, or connector dash, instead of a hyphenation marker to connect the two years.